# Setting global variables in webpack for front-end config?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a different URL for our api depending if it's development or production for a react app.

Using webpack, how can I set an env var like `__API_URL__` and then change that depending if it's **built using** `webpack.config.dev` vs `webpack.config.prod`

I thought the answer may be in `webpack.DefinePlugin` but no luck.

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  __API_URL__: 'localhost:3005',
}),
```

I'd expect `__API_URL__` to be available as a global but no such luck.

What would be the right way to do this? Also key thing is that no express server on the prod deploy. So this has to happen during the build...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael Rasoahaingo said, the `DefinePlugin` works similar like replacing values with regular expressions: It replaces the value literally in your source code. I would not recommend to use the `DefinePlugin` for this kind of task.

If you want to switch configs based on the environment, you could use [`resolve.alias`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias) for that. Just import your config like this:

```
var config = require("config");
```

and then add a mapping in your `webpack.config.js`:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
       config$: require.resolve("path/to/real/config/file")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked beautifully. Edited comment to show it's in resolve handler.

Answer (score 1):

DefinePlugin is not working as you expected. It doesn't expose `__API_URL__` as a global variable.

According to the [documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin):  "The values will be inlined into the code which allows a minification pass to remove the redundant conditional."

So, it will find all occurence of `__API_URL__` and changes it.

```
var apiUrl = __API_URL__
```

and

```
__API_URL__: '"localhost:3005"' // note the ' and "
```

become

```
var apiUrl = "localhost:3005"
```